# I am not behind a proxy but still getting error while installing packages using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-request

### here is the output from npm-debug.log

1. info it worked if it ends with ok
2. verbose cli [ 'D:\Softwares and Codes\NodeJS\NodeJS\\node.exe',
3. verbose cli   'D:\Softwares and Codes\NodeJS\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
4. verbose cli   'install',
5. verbose cli   'gulp',
6. verbose cli   '--save' ]
7. info using npm@2.11.3
8. info using node@v0.12.7
9. verbose install initial load of C:\Users\Mayur\Desktop\Node\package.json
10. warn package.json sampleapp@1.0.0 No repository field.
11. warn package.json sampleapp@1.0.0 No README data
12. verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\Mayur\Desktop\Node\package.json
13. silly cache add args [ 'gulp', null ]
14. verbose cache add spec gulp
15. silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'gulp',
16. silly cache add   scope: null,
17. silly cache add   name: 'gulp',
18. silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
19. silly cache add   spec: '*',
20. silly cache add   type: 'range' }
21. silly addNamed gulp@*
22. verbose addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for gulp
23. silly addNameRange { name: 'gulp', range: '*', hasData: false }
24. silly mapToRegistry name gulp
25. silly mapToRegistry using default registry
26. silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
27. silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
28. verbose addNameRange registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp not in flight; fetching
29. verbose request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
30. verbose request no auth needed
31. info attempt registry request try #1 at 8:00:49 PM
32. verbose request id 8da3a5a06ccf7a86
33. http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
34. info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
35. info attempt registry request try #2 at 8:01:20 PM
36. http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
37. info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
38. info attempt registry request try #3 at 8:02:41 PM
39. http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
40. verbose stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
41. verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
42. verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
43. verbose cwd C:\Users\Mayur\Desktop\Node
44. error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
45. error argv "D:\Softwares and Codes\NodeJS\NodeJS\\node.exe" "D:\Softwares and Codes\NodeJS\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp" "--save"
46. error node v0.12.7
47. error npm  v2.11.3
48. error code ETIMEDOUT
49. error errno ETIMEDOUT
50. error syscall connect
51. error network connect ETIMEDOUT
52. error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
53. error network and is related to network connectivity.
54. error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
55. error network
56. error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
57. error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
58. verbose exit [ 1, true ]

### I have already tried

1. set registry to http://registry.npmjs.org/
2. set strict ssl to false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Did you check your internet settings to check whether the proxy settings are enabled?

2) Did you check environment variables for `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`? If those values are set, remove them and problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks! The "npm config rm proxy" and "npm config rm https-proxy" was not working. So, I have manually changed .npmrc and it worked.

Comment: Glad if I were able to help you in some way.I find that setting `HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY` is the easiest way to configure proxy on all applications(all applications that I use). Ex: git, npm. It is less confusing and we can add/remove proxy settings in one location.